# Azure Web App Service, customize docker runtime commands

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I want the image I'm pushing into azure container registry that's being used by azure web app to be run with custom runtime flags, i.e. `docker run --device /dev/snd myimage:mytag`

I saw another post about this that said it wasn't possible but it was from a few years ago. Does anyone know if this can be done? Or if there's a way I can achieve the same effect in the dockerfile itself?

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: Was there any feature/bug request raised for this? Any Idea?